# Flutter _AssertionError when i use putFile

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, file-upload, firebase-storage

I get this error

[image]

Here is my upload function:

```
 Future uploadFile() async{  
    final path = "images/$email/";
    final file = File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/folder"); 
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    ref.putFile(file);
  }
```

Comment: Please see how to post code https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also face the issue while uploading files using `putFile()` function. So I try this.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as prefixStorage;

final int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
final XFile? image = await picker.pickVideo(source:ImageSource.gallery);
final prefixStorage.Reference firebaseStorageRef = firebaseStorage
            .ref()
            .child('images')
            .child(
                '/$timestamp${image?.path.substring(image.path.indexOf('.'), image.path.length)}');
await firebaseStorageRef.putData(await image.readAsBytes());
final String? imageURL = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
```